# How can I have a full width spotify playlist embed iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, spotify

I have created an embed in my site from the spotify playlist iframe enbed option.

I want to make it full width and this is what ~I have so far:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#playlist-container iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]').each( function() {
        var widthC = $('#playlist-container iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]').find('#outerWidgetContainer');
        widthC.css('width',$(this).parent().css('width'));
        $(this).css('width',$(this).parent().css('width'));
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

The issue is that this element `'#outerWidgetContainer'` has got inline styling of 320px.

What would be ideal is if I could just access the element and get rid of that width.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why this line `$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));`?

Comment: thats to store the src url as a variable so on resize it does not get lost